# Compiler optimizations, divide macro expansions

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I have following piece of code,

Scenario 1

```
/* get count of elements in an array */
#define COUNT(x)         sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])

struct Data data[] = {/* some data goes here */};

int count = COUNT(data);
```

Scenario 2

```
#define TOTAL            32
#define EACH              4
int count = (TOTAL/EACH)
```

I know macros are resolved during preprocessing and sizeof is a compile time operator, but what about the division: does it get optimised during compilation ?

Is there any tool to see the optimizations done by the compiler ?

Comment: that tool is your compiler - probably it has a flag to make it show preprocessed output as well as the assembly generated

Comment: you can see the assembly code to find this.

Comment: I'd expect any mature compiler to do the division during compilation (in both cases) if told to fully optimise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you can let the compiler show you the generated assembly code. With Visual C++ you can do that with the `/Fa<file>` option. `gcc` has the `-S` option.

As for your question: Most compilers should precompute constant expressions, at least at optimisation levels higher than `O0`.

Let's see with your example scenarios:

```
#define COUNT(x)         sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])
int data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int count = COUNT(data);
```

Compiled with `cl /c /Fascenario1.asm scenario1.c` yields:

```
...
PUBLIC  _data
PUBLIC  _count
_DATA   SEGMENT
_data   DD  01H
    DD  02H
    DD  03H
    DD  04H
    DD  05H
_count  DD  05H
_DATA   ENDS
END
```

You see the value for `count` close to the end, and it's indeed 5. So the compiler computed the value even with no optimisation turned on.

Your second scenario:

```
#define TOTAL            32
#define EACH              4
int count = (TOTAL/EACH);
```

yields

```
...
PUBLIC  _count
_DATA   SEGMENT
_count  DD  08H
_DATA   ENDS
END
```

where the expression was precomputed as well.

It's not uncommon at higher optimisation levels for the compiler to even evalute more complex expressions when you pass compile-time constants. As an example, I once looked at the code of three different ways of swapping two integers and once I turned optimisation on the compiler simply threw out the call to the swap method entirely, replacing the arguments to my test `printf` with the already-swapped values.

Comment: Note, C compiler should precompute any constant expression in order to compile code like `int x[expression];`, so they do it in any optimization level.